# Run OpenSCAP locally on Windows

Tags: windows, security, openscap

Please tell me if I am missing something here. OpenSCAP will not currently allow you to run scans locally against a Windows machine.

I have read posts on Experts Exchange that lead me to believe that there might be a workaround to this problem, but it would require OpenSCAP base to be installed. Currently there is no Windows supported download for OpenSCAP base.

Here is my question. Is OpenSCAP posix compliant? Might it be possible to install and run OpenSCAP base on the newer versions of Windows with Unix services enabled?

Just a thought.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OpenSCAP (OpenSCAP library and command line application) has recently enabled Windows support in its master branch.
It is not complete, but it is working, as this Twitter post suggests: https://twitter.com/OpenSCAP/status/989107760464834560

The Windows version has not been released yet. However, it is possible to build it from source code on Windows using Visual Studio 2017. https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap/blob/master/docs/manual/manual.adoc#building-openscap-on-windows-using-visual-studio

Using the GUI (Workbench) is not possible now.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSCAP Microsoft Windows support has been removed as of Feb 2022 because no one in the community stepped up to help maintain Windows support.  1.3.4 is the last OpenSCAP version to include some semblance of Windows support.

- https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap?tab=readme-ov-file#microsoft-windows-support
- https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap/blob/maint-1.3/docs/windows.md