# OpenSCAP for windows target

Tags: windows-server-2012, openscap

I am searching for OpenSCAP support for windows target servers. Currently OpenSCAP does not allow to run scans locally against a Windows machine. Please check this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/912940/run-openscap-locally-on-windows). But it does not have enough information on it.

Does anyone know any workaround for OpenSCAP checking windows target servers for compliance ?
Or is there any other way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is an alpha version of OpenSCAP for Windows. https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap/releases/tag/1.3.0_alpha1
This version is command-line only and implements only a subset of checks, but might be worth trying.